# Extjs reloading radiogroup with updated radio items array

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, radio-button, extjs3

I have an `Ext.Window` that contains a `formPanel`. The formPanel has a `radiogroup` item which loads a `radioItemsArray`. Initially I create each `radioItem` based on data from `myRadioStore` and is mapped to the `radiogroup` in formpanel. This works fine, see code below:

```
this.radioItemsArr = [];
    Ext.each(myRadioStore.data.items, function(itm, i, all) {
        var radioItem = new Ext.form.Radio({
                    id : itm.data.dataId,
                    // custom radio label with text + images
                    boxLabel: 
                        '<b>Data id:</b> ' +  itm.data.dataId + '<br/>' +
                        '<b>Data:</b> ' +  itm.data.dataDetail + '<br/>' +
                        '<p>' + '<img id style="imgStyle" src=\"' + itm.data.url + '\"/></p>',                          
                    name: 'radioName',
                    inputValue: itm.data.dataId ,
                    height: 'auto',
                    checked: false
                });
        this.radioItemsArr.push(radioItem);
    }, this);

this.myForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            border: false,
            id:'my-form',
            frame : true,
            layout : 'fit',
            items: [{
                    autoScroll: true,
                    id: 'myFormId',
                    defaults: {
                        labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        title: 'Custom Title',
                        items: [{
                            // custom description text set on form load
                            id: 'descId',
                            style : { marginTop: '15px', border:'5px'}
                        }]
                    }, {
                        title: 'Select an item from below',
                        items: [{
                            anchor: '0',
                            autoHeight: true,
                            xtype: 'radiogroup',
                            hideLabels: true,
                            id: 'allRadiosID',
                            items: [
                                this.radioItemsArr
                            ],
                        }]
                    }
                ],
            }],
            buttonAlign :'center',
            buttons: [{
                // save button
            },{
                // cancel button
            }]
        });
```

This loads all the radio buttons correctly the first time. But when `myRadioStore` is updated with new data from server (it happens when user clicks a button), I want my form panel to update with the new radio buttons. So when `myRadioStore` is updated, I remove all items in `radioItemsArray` and then creates new `radioItem` by looping through the store and pushing to `radioItemsArr`. I can see that the `radioItemsArr` has new radio button options. But the `radiogroup` in `formpanel` is not getting refreshed.

Calling `Ext.getCmp('my-form').doLayout()` don't seem to work. Any thought/comments?

Edit: I'm using extjs 3.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling layout/render on form did not work in case of `radioGroup`. So every time `myRadioStore` is updated, you need to remove the `radiogroup` from the form, create a `radio` array from `myRadioStore` and then re-add the radio`g`roup array back in the `form`.

Something like:

```
Ext.getCmp('my-form').remove(Ext.getCmp('allRadiosID'), true);
// recreate `radioItemsArr[]` array of radios from updated `radioItemsArr` and add it back to form
Ext.getCmp('my-form').add(new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
                                anchor: '0',
                                autoHeight: true,
                                id: 'allRadiosID',
                                items: [
                                    radioItemsArr
                                ]
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is binding the store to the radio group directly.  You could add a listener to the store, with the `update` listener to then programatically add the new store radios.

Untested code but should be near-enough.

```
// Add a listener to the store, this can be defined in the `listeners` property of the store config too.

myRadioStore.addListener('update', function () {
    // get the radio group and remove all items
    var radioGroup = Ext.getCmp('allRadiosID');
    radioGroup.removeAll();
    // call the function to renew the radio array.
    getRadioArray();
    radioGroup.add(this.radioItemsArr);
    // Optionally update the container form too
    Ext.getCmp('my-form').doLayout();
}, this);


this.radioItemsArr = [];

function getRadioArray() {
    this.radioItemsArr = [];
    Ext.each(myRadioStore.data.items, function (itm, i, all) {
        var radioItem = new Ext.form.Radio({
            id: itm.data.dataId,
            // custom radio label with text + images
            boxLabel:
                '<b>Data id:</b> ' + itm.data.dataId + '<br/>' +
                '<b>Data:</b> ' + itm.data.dataDetail + '<br/>' +
                '<p>' + '<img id style="imgStyle" src=\"' + itm.data.url + '\"/></p>',
            name: 'radioName',
            inputValue: itm.data.dataId,
            height: 'auto',
            checked: false
        });
        this.radioItemsArr.push(radioItem);
    }, this);
}

getRadioArray();

this.myForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    border: false,
    id: 'my-form',
    frame: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        autoScroll: true,
        id: 'myFormId',
        defaults: {
            labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;'
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Custom Title',
            items: [{
                // custom description text set on form load
                id: 'descId',
                style: {
                    marginTop: '15px',
                    border: '5px'
                }
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Select an item from below',
            items: [{
                anchor: '0',
                autoHeight: true,
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                hideLabels: true,
                id: 'allRadiosID',
                items: [this.radioItemsArr]
            }]
        }]
    }],
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    buttons: [{
        // save button
    }, {
        // cancel button
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks but darn.. there is no radioGroup.removeAll() function in extjs 3.4. Looks like I might have to remove the radioGroup, load the array and readd array to radiogroup and finally add the radiogroup to form. But removing radiogroup from form by `Ext.getCmp('myFormId').remove('allRadiosID');` don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @kriver sorry I was using the 4.2 documentation I have...  as for the `remove` method of the `form` in 3.4, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.BasicForm-method-remove it expects a `field` not an ID  so you're gonna have to get a reference to it e.g. `Ext.getCmp('myFormId').remove(Ext.getCmp('allRadiosID'));`

Comment: Even that and a doLayout/render doesn't seem to work. I'm thinking this might not be possible in extjs 3.4